# how to replace last space into new line in bash or perl

Tags: bash, perl, shell

I have a space delimited text file, like-

```
tae-miR16a     Ta#S1798083_1          MRRGTILVVSWS    
tae-miR16a     Ta#S1798783_5          MAPMEAEEPDQQ
tae-miR16a     Ta#S1797083_7  REVERSE SENSE   MEDXYSSGSX
tae-miR16a     Ta#S1987083_8  REVERSE SENSE   MNSRMTCCSAISSEWATANFASVCSM
```

I want to put last column into new line like-

```
tae-miR16a     Ta#S1798083_1
MRRGTILVVSWS
tae-miR16a     Ta#S1798783_5
MAPMEAEEPDQQ
tae-miR16a     Ta#S1797083_7  REVERSE SENSE
MEDXYSSGSX
tae-miR16a     Ta#S1987083_8  REVERSE SENSE
MNSRMTCCSAISSEWATANFASVCSM
```

Answer (score 3):

This one-line Perl program will do as you ask

```
perl -pe's/\s+(\S+)\s*\z/\n$1\n/' infile > outfile
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this with sed:

```
sed 's/ \([^ ]*\)$/\n\1/' file
```

Output:

```
tae-miR16a Ta#S1798083_1
MRRGTILVVSWS
tae-miR16a Ta#S1798783_5
MAPMEAEEPDQQ
tae-miR16a Ta#S1797083_7 REVERSE SENSE
MEDXYSSGSX
tae-miR16a Ta#S1987083_8 REVERSE SENSE
MNSRMTCCSAISSEWATANFASVCSM
```

Add option `-i` to edit file in place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` with extended regex:

```
sed -r 's/[[:space:]]+([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*)$/\n\1/' file
```

Output:

```
tae-miR16a     Ta#S1798083_1
MRRGTILVVSWS    
tae-miR16a     Ta#S1798783_5
MAPMEAEEPDQQ
tae-miR16a     Ta#S1797083_7  REVERSE SENSE
MEDXYSSGSX
tae-miR16a     Ta#S1987083_8  REVERSE SENSE
MNSRMTCCSAISSEWATANFASVCSM
```

Answer (score -2):

i am getting following output using above given command:

```
zma-miR827-5p   Zm#S48299167_11         MLFSPYISFLNSELATHYPYLNLGIRYG
zma-miR827-5p   Zm#S48299167_12 REVERSE
SENSE   MGCKLTIEKTYIR
zma-miR827-5p   Zm#S48299167_13 REVERSE
SENSE   MRMSTATRQIFT
```

Here i found a little bit long command pipeline to resolve the issue:

```
cat inputfilenae | sed 's/\s/\__/g' |sed 's/\__$//g' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\__"} {$NF="\n"$NF}{print}' | sed 's/\__$//g' |sed 's/\__$//g'  > outputfilename
```